# which one among none/nodev/debugfs shosuld I use to mount debugfs?

Tags: linux, mount, mount-point

I am trying to enable debug in ath9k kernel driver module.

As debug uses `debugfs`, I need to mount debugfs. But people and internet are suggesting a little bit differnt mount commnad:

```
# (Note) mount usage: mount -t type dev dir
mount -t debugfs debugfs /sys/kernel/debug
mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug
mount -t debugfs nodev /sys/kernel/debug
```

I am wondering whether all of three commnads have same effect and  result.
If so, which role does `dev` in the middle of the command do?

Currently, I think that debugfs is already mounted on my system by typing `mount`:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
...
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
...
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dev in the middle of the command is the device (eg: /dev/sda1) in case of real filesystems but since this is a virtualized filesystem in RAM it is only necessary to specify the type and the kernel knows what to do next.

According to the official documentation the correct way is this:

`mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug`

The details are here:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/debugfs.txt